# Are we forced to make tasks in individual modules in ZF2 CMS?

Tags: php, module, zend-framework2, content-management-system

I've created a Zend Framework 2 based CMS and I'm using it in my projects. Should I have individual modules for every task in my CMS?

For example, I have news, gallery, users, statistics, messages etc in my CMS, and now I have a module named "Application" for all of them, another module named "Admin" for managing them, and a module named "auth" for managing users and admins. Is this structure OK or should I take them apart and make some more modules for every part of my CMS?

Comment: When posting a question, please keep in mind that people will have to read it to answer it, so it should be well formatted and easily readable. Please keep an eye on the punctuation: colons don't ever need a space before them, and ellipses should be used sparingly  or better not used at all, as they make a text harder to read. And of course there should be capital letters wherever English grammar dictates them to be : )

Comment: I was thinking all about the problem not the writing , but thanks anyway.

Comment: Writing proper text is just about being polite to readers, and it signifes that one appreciates their effort by making his own effort of asking a well written question : )

Answer (score 0):

The idea of a module is something that you can reuse in another project.

If your code (functionality) is specific to your application and it will not be reusable in other application, then it can be placed under your Application module.

Comment: yup that is , but this is my project structure and that means i copy some parts of my this application from this project  to another application on another project whenever i need, instead of copying the modules. and i want to know is it right or not?

Comment: If you know that a peace of code will be reusable in another project, then it is a good candidate for creating a new module.